# How to add a new inittab entry - a script

Tags: scripting

```
vi /etc/inittab
startfoobar:3:respawn:/root/startfoobar.sh # added this line
telinit q
```

But the /root/startfoobar.sh doesn't starts. Why? SLES 11. What am I missing?

```
cat /root/startfoobar.sh
sleep 30
```

Comment: First off, `inittab(5)` tells you that the first field (`startfoobar` in your case) may only be four characters long.  Other causes might be missing shebang in your script (try placing `#!/bin/sh` into the first line) or missing execute permissions (try `chmod +x /root/startfoobar.sh`).

Comment: yupp, it is working if shorter than 5 char..